# Stuck on a string return

Tags: javascript

I've completely drawn a blank on how to get a string to return properly inside of an if statement.

```
function truncateString(str, num) {
  var s = str;
  var n = num;
  if(s > n.length) {
    return s.slice(0, n - 3).concat("...");
  } else return s;
}
truncateString("This string is too long", 11);
```

I know I've got it all wrong but can't figure out how to make it work. 
Please do not post the solution, just remind me how to return the string correctly within an if statement.

Comment: What is your expected output? What is your current output?

Comment: This question is [off-topic (#2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, you just swapped the arguments by mistake.

```
if(s > n.length)
```

should be

```
if(s.length > n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically a `number` do not have a property called `length` with it,

```
if(s.length > n)
```

Full code would be,

```
function truncateString(str, num){
  var s = str;
  var n = num;
  if(s.length > n) {
    return s.slice(0, n - 3).concat("...");
  }
  else {
   return s;
  }
}

truncateString("This string is too long", 11);
//"This str..."
```

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the `.length` property on the wrong object. (You're asking for the number length instead of the string length). This means your if statement's primary condition never executes, and the function returns the whole string every time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have at least one error on the logic.  Instead of comparing s with n.length, you need to compare str/s length with num/n.

And I think what you were trying to use is the conditional ternary operator ?:

The next is a modified version of yours.

```
function truncateString(str, num) 
{
  var s = str;
  var n = num;

return (s.length > n) ?  s.slice(0, n - 3).concat("...") : s;

}

alert(truncateString("This string is too long", 11));
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable 'n' holds a primitive value but not an object.That's why there is no 'length' property of variable 'n'. So n.length statement returns 'undefined' value. Finally s > n.length statement returns false and if block never executes. You could use s.length instead.Here 's' holds string value and string is also primitive value in JavaScript but at run time string value converts into its wrapper String Object whenever you try to access any property of it including length property.